# Monotonicity of the cycle index polynomial under restriction

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory

The [cycle index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index) (polynomial) of the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$ is given by the formula:
$$Z(\mathfrak{S}_n)(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{1j_1+2j_2+\cdots+nj_n=n}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k^{j_k}}{k^{j_k}j_k!}.$$

Some examples: $Z(\mathfrak{S}_1)=x_1, Z(\mathfrak{S}_2)=\frac1{2!}(x_1+x_2)$ and
$$Z(\mathfrak{S}_3)=\frac1{3!}(x_1^3+3x_1x_2+2x_3).$$

I wish to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Assume $1\geq x_1\geq x_2\geq \cdots\geq 0$. Is this true? If so, is there a combinatorial reason for it?
> $$Z(\mathfrak{S}_{n+1})(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})\leq Z(\mathfrak{S}_n)(x_1,\dots,x_n).$$

Comment: If $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_n=0$ then this inequality reads $x_{n+1}/(n+1) \le 0$ which is false.

Comment: Many other examples of this nature, e.g. if $x_i$ is the indicator function of even numbers, the cycle index polynomial is zero whenever $n$ is odd, and positive otherwise. In particular, the sequence is not non-increasing.

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky: Ouch! I made a mistake in the inequalities for the $x_i$'s. Fixed now.

Comment: Possibly you can use Touchard’s theorem (in other words the exponential generating function of these polynomials) to show this.

Comment: In line with Sam Hopkins's comment: we have
$$Z(\mathfrak{S}_{n})(x_1,\ldots,x_{n})-Z(\mathfrak{S}_{n-1})(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}) = Z(\mathfrak{S}_n)(x_1-1,\ldots,x_n-1),$$
e.g. through an identity of generating functions: $\exp(\sum u^i x_i/i) (1-u) = \exp( \sum u^i (x_i-1)/i)$. So it is the same as showing $Z(\mathfrak{S}_n)(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \le 0$ for $0\ge x_1 \ge x_2 \ge \cdots \ge -1$. Perhaps the combiatorial/algebraic recurrence $n Z(\mathfrak{S}_{n})(x_1,\ldots,x_{n}) = x_n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} Z(\mathfrak{S}_{n-i})(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-i})\cdot x_i$ is relevant.

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky or Sam Hopkins: if you expand on your comments in the other box, it might help even more.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan I don't have any answer to post, sorry.